# How to write a column name with dot (".") in the SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a column name using "." with no success

sample:

```
SELECT PrmTable.Value = MAX(Value)
FROM TempTable
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(Value) AS PrmTable.Value
FROM TempTable
```

Any idea ?

Comment: try enclosing it in double quotes - SELECT MAX(Value) AS "PrmTable.Value"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just enclose it in square brackets, and it will work

e.g.

```
SELECT MAX(Value) AS [PrmTable.Value]
FROM TempTable
```

Answer (score 13):

I would not recommend you use field names which always require you to enclose the name in brackets, it becomes a pain.

Also the period is used in SQL Server to denote schema and database name separators. Using your field name the full name for a field becomes:

```
[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName].[FieldName.WithPeriod]
```

That just looks odd and would probably confuse other DBAs. Use an underscore to separate words in your field names, it's a much more common style:

```
[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName].[FieldName_WithUnderscore]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [PrmTable.Value] = MAX(Value)

FROM TempTable

or

SELECT MAX(Value) AS [PrmTable.Value]
```