# RSQLite couldnt read column names with "."

Tags: r, sqlite

I am trying to use RSQLite to read in tables from my database. All the tables have column names with ".".

For example: my test table has 2 columns: index, first.name

How do I write a query to filter test table with first name column:

My code is:

```
dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE 'first.name' = 'Joe'")
```

and it gave me an error:

```
Error: no such column: first.name
```

Comment: dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE first.name = 'Joe' ") Is it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work: *Adding []*

```r
dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE [first.name] = 'Joe'")
```

See the below thread:
[How to write a column name with dot (".") in the SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634501/how-to-write-a-column-name-with-dot-in-the-select-clause)